# Are Naruto's shadow clones separate, conscious entities?

Tags: naruto

When Naruto creates his shadow clones, they are obviously physical, separate things. Are they also separately conscious? Do they die when the jutsu ends?

Comment: KAGE BUNSHIN NO JUTSU!!

Comment: Related: (Anime & Mange SE) [How does a shadow clone identify itself as a shadow clone?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/12870/310) | [Does Naruto consciously control his clones?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4229/310)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shadow clones are self-aware, but are also aware that they are only temporary clones. When they are disrupted, their experiences seem to go back to Naruto, which is why he can gain new information from them. In one of the filler episodes of the anime, he does maintain a clone long enough that it gains its own identity, and doesn't want to be dispelled because it sees that as a death of self. But in general, they are just reflections of him, and where that when they "die", they just return to him.

Comment: The episode might be https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Revenge_of_the_Shadow_Clones. I can't watch now.

Comment: I believe filler episodes are generally considered non-canon by the fandom. Also, the "rebelling" clones that can't be released by Naruto in "Revenge of the Shadow Clones" were just a dream (of a clone). It didn't actually happen.